# Unable to correctly include jQuery in a legacy Wordpress application with multisites

Tags: multisite, jquery

Our legacy multi-site Wordpress application with Wordpress version 6.2 and jQuery version 3.6.4 was working fine so far. We did a PHP upgrade, from version 7.2 to 7.4. Since then, jQuery is not loading for the microsites, even though in the admin logged in view, it is loading fine and previews are showing fine. Also, the main site is working fine.

I checked that there is default loading of jQuery from `wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.min.js`. I tried a fresh inclusion of jQuery, like this -

```
function my_jquery_enqueue() {
        wp_deregister_script('jquery');
        wp_register_script('jquery', 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.4.min.js', array(), null, false);
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
}
if (!is_admin()) add_action("wp_enqueue_scripts", "my_jquery_enqueue", 11);
```

After this, I can see the old jQuery inclusion is gone and the new one is added -

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.4.min.js' id='jquery-js'></script>
```

Now, the microsite is working fine, but the main site is not loading properly, and throwing following javascript errors -

```
jquery-3.6.4.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: e.indexOf is not a function
    at S.fn.load (jquery-3.6.4.min.js:2:85207)
    at preloader-script.js:1:16

(index):78 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'querySelector')
    at (index):78:28

jquery-3.6.4.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: e.indexOf is not a function
    at S.fn.load (jquery-3.6.4.min.js:2:85207)
    at jquery.waypoints.js?ver=1.7:495:15
    at jquery.waypoints.js?ver=1.7:21:14
    at jquery.waypoints.js?ver=1.7:23:5
    at jquery.waypoints.js?ver=1.7:500:4
```

What am I missing?

**Update 1**

The error I was getting on the microsites before the swap to CDN version is -

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at (index):631:2
```

Comment: the jquery errors in your final code block are unlikely to be WordPress related, they look like a general JS question, and one that can't be answered without the associated HTML. I'd also strongly advise against deregistering jQuery and using CDNs as it's bad for performance and privacy. I can't see any JS code, HTML, or the original errors you had before swapping to the CDN version in your question, can you edit them in? There's also `jquery.waypoints.js` and `preloader-script.js` in the error but they aren't mentioned in your question

Comment: it could also be that you're unaware of jQuerys noconflct mode and have use `$()` everywhere instead of `jQuery()` or using a wrapper to allow `$()`

Comment: The error I was getting before the swap to CDN version is - `Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at (index):631:2`. Added same to question.

Comment: The preloader-script.js and jquery.waypoints.js are from plugins directory - `wp-content/plugins/the-preloader/js/preloader-script.js` and `wp-content/plugins/livemesh-siteorigin-widgets/assets/js/jquery.waypoints.js`

Comment: the initial error could have been an ordering problem from not declaring dependencies properly when using `wp_enqueue_script`, you should also be sure to test this without the preloader script as that changes things enormously, and you can't ask for help with 3rd party plugins here as they're offtopic and not in this stacks scope

Comment: I just removed the `wp_deregister_script('jquery');` call inside my newly added `my_jquery_enqueue()` and it now works for both! The main site and the micro site now include the original instance of jquery, so effectively my CDN is not being included, but still the errors are gone. I am clueless what happened.

Comment: never use the CDN version, plugins in WP expect to use the version that comes with WP and pinning to a CDN version means no more jQuery updates, it also means reduced performance as browsers cache resources on a per domain basis so loading it on site 1 doesn't mean it's cached for site 2, both have separate caches, and it isn't possible to use HTTP2 compression/multiplexing to speed up the transfer if it's on a CDN unless all your resources are on that same CDN server